# php return variable to external javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

jquery code

```
var test;
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: dataLink,
           url: "find.php",
           success: function(data){
                      $("#status").html(data);
               },
           error: function() {
                    alert("error.");
               }
      });
```

part of php file find.php

```
 $result = $db->query($query);
 $r = $result->Fetch();
 $_pStopa =  $r['proc'];
 echo '<span class="label label-info">'.trim($r['naziv']).", Prodajna cena:".$r['prodajna_cena'].", PS: ".$r['naziv_stope']."</span>";
 echo '<script> _setArt('.$r['prodajna_cena'].');</script>';
```

It is necessary to test the variable to return result of $ _pstopa.

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 1):

you might consider using json_encode and do the entire templating in javascript 
(http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

then it would look like

php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
[...]
$result = $db->query($query);
$r = $result->Fetch();
echo json_encode($r);
```

for the js

```
           $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     data: dataLink,
                     url: "find.php",
                     success: function(data){
                       var response= $.parseJSON(data);
                       /* your testing of the response data here */
                       _setArt(response.proc);
                       $("#status").html('<span class="label label-info">'+response.naziv+', Prodajna cena:' + response.prodajna_cena + ', PS: '+response.naziv_stope+'</span>');
                     },
                     error: function() {
                         alert("error.");
                     }

                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what information you want to load from the database.
But it's always better to check if variables have a correct value.
Especially on connection interfaces.